# I would like to delay something after it's been clicked

Tags: jquery-animate, settimeout, delay

I'm creating a multiple choice question program and I have it so that once the correct answer is chosen a new question is generated.

Although I want it to go to the next question automatically, I want it to delay for about 0.5 seconds so the user can see that their answer is correct.

I chose to remove the class and replace it with another class so that the background changes colour. Once the new question comes up I want all the colours to return to normal, so I once again remove the new class and replace it with the old class.

If I don't advance to the new question automatically, the colours come up just the way I like them, but if I create it so that it moves on automatically, I am unable to keep the display the same.

After searching through the forums I read that setTimeout should work, but I haven't had much success. I have also tried doing animations so that it takes time, but that didn't work for me either. The animations worked fine, but it still went on to the new set of questions.

I'll include the whole program as it might be better but the section I'm working on is under the function check().

I've been trying to figure out how to delay something for a long time but have been completely unsuccessful. Oh, please be kind to me, I have very little experience. I have only learned how to do javascript by doing the khan academy course. Thanks!

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Project: listening to sounds </title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <!-- ***************** CSS styles ***************** -->
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: comic sans ms, sans-serif;
                background-image: url("background.jpg");
                background-color:  rgb(216, 252, 252);

            }
            form {
                font-size: 1.2em;
            }

            #text {
                background-color: wheat;
                width: 150px;
                height: 25px;
                color: blue;
                font-size: 1em;

            }

            .SoundBite {
                float: left;
                clear: none;
                position: absolute;
                top: 130px;
                left: 100px;
                padding: 5px;
                background: darkblue;
                color: white;
                height: 120px;
                width: 200px;
                border-radius: 50px;
                margin: auto;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
                font-size: 5em;
            }

            .SoundBite:hover {
                background-color: darkgreen;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .Score {
                float: right;
                clear: none;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50px;
                left: 140px;
                padding: 5px;
                background: darkblue;
                border-color: pink;
                border: 5px;
                opacity: 0.8;
                color: white;
                height: 45px;
                width: 120px;
                border-radius: 50px;
                margin: auto;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
                font-size: 2em;
                pointer-events: none;
            }           

            .Answer {
                position: absolute;
                color: white;
                height: 45px;
                width: 120px;
                padding: 5px;
                border-radius: 25px;
                margin: auto;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
                font-size: 2em;
                background-color: darkblue;
            }

            .AnswerCorrect {
                position: absolute;
                color: white;
                height: 45px;
                width: 120px;
                padding: 5px;
                border-radius: 25px;
                margin: auto;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
                font-size: 2em;
                background-color: green;            
            }

            .Answer:hover {
                background-color: #e44404;
                cursor: pointer; 

            }

            .AnswerWrong {
                position: absolute;
                color: white;
                height: 45px;
                width: 120px;
                padding: 5px;
                border-radius: 25px;
                margin: auto;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
                font-size: 2em;
                background-color: red;
            }

            #Answer1 {
                top: 20px;
                left: 400px;

            }
            #Answer2 {
                top: 85px;
                left: 400px;

            }
            #Answer3 {
                top: 150px;
                left: 400px;
            }
            #Answer4 {
                top: 220px;
                left: 400px;
            }

            #Answer5 {
                top: 290px;
                left: 400px;
            }


        </style>
    </head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <body>

    <audio id="audio" src="audio/rug.mp3" autostart="false" ></audio>
    <audio id = "win" src="audio/win.mp3" autostart = "true"></audio>
    <audio id = "lose" src = "audio/lose.mp3" autstart = "true"></audio>

    <a onclick="playSound();"><div span class="SoundBite"><i class="fa fa-file-sound-o" id="audio" src="audio/rug.mp3" autostart="false" style="font-size:64px;color:skyblue"></i></div></a>
    <a onclick ="checkAnswer = 1; check();"><div class = "Answer" id="Answer1">1</div>
    <a onclick ="checkAnswer = 2; check();"><div class = "Answer" id="Answer2">2</div>
    <a onclick ="checkAnswer = 3; check();"><div class = "Answer" id="Answer3">3</div>
    <a onclick ="checkAnswer = 4; check();"><div class = "Answer" id="Answer4">4</div>
    <a onclick ="checkAnswer = 5; check();"><div class = "Answer" id="Answer5">5</div>
    <div class = "Score">Score</div>


    <!-- <a onclick ="next();"><div id = "Next">Start</div> -->



    <!-- ********************************* Javascript programming follows ********************************* -->

    <script>
    $(function() {
    });

        // declare the variables to be used ... do I need global variables? Maybe I should think about these...
        var word, ext, directory, wordPosition, decoyWordPosition, answerPosition, decoyAnswerPosition, answer, checkAnswer, correct, incorrect, tries;
        directory = "audio/";
        ext = ".mp3";
        correct = 0;
        incorrect = 0;
        tries = 0;



        // list of words that are spoken
        word = ["dam", "dog", "dug", "cat", "cot", "cut", "ran", "rot", "rug"]; 
        wordPosition = Math.floor(Math.random()*word.length); // returns a random array wordPosition


    /***************************************************************************
     ** Functions:
     **
     **************************************************************************/


    // function to display word
    function displayWord() {
        //$(".SoundBite").text(word[wordPosition]);
        //$("#audio").attr("src", directory+word[wordPosition]+ext);
    }

    // function to display the answer in one of the positions that are assigned
    function displayAnswer(answerNumber, wordNumber) {
        $("#Answer"+answerNumber).text(word[wordNumber]);
        $("#audio").attr("src", directory+word[wordPosition]+ext);
    }   

    // function to play the sound 
    function playSound() {        
          var sound = document.getElementById("audio");
          sound.play();
      }

    // function to play a winning sound
    function win() {
        var sound = document.getElementById("win");
        sound.play();
    }

    // function to play a losing sound
    function lose() {
        var sound = document.getElementById("lose");
        sound.play();
    }

    function timer() {
        new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    }

    function check() {
            if (answer == checkAnswer) {
                //$("#Answer"+checkAnswer).animate({height: "45px", opacity: '0'})
                                        //.animate({height: "45px", opacity: '1.0'});
                $("#Answer"+checkAnswer).animate({height: "45px", opacity: '0'})
                                        .animate({height: "45px", opacity: '1.0'})
                                        .removeClass("Answer").addClass("AnswerCorrect");
                win();
                correct++;
                tries++;
                refresh();

                next();
                // need a delay function -- can't get it to work.


            } else {
                $("#Answer"+checkAnswer).removeClass("Answer").addClass("AnswerWrong"); //css({'background-color': 'red'});
                lose();
                incorrect++;
                tries++;

            }

            // write in the score
            $(".Score").text(Math.round(correct/tries*100)+"%");
    }

    // making a function to populate the answers 
    function populateAnswers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (answerPosition < 6) {
            if (decoyWordPosition == wordPosition) {
                answer=answerPosition
            }
            displayAnswer(answerPosition, decoyWordPosition);
            answerPosition++;
            decoyWordPosition++;
            if (decoyWordPosition >= word.length) { // want to make sure that the words are within the array
                decoyWordPosition = 1               // reset to the beginning to 'wrap' the array.
                }

            } else {
                answerPosition = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // using a random generator to place the answer in a random spot 1 through 4
    function randomGenerator() {
    answerPosition = Math.floor(Math.random()*4)+1;
    }

    // returns a random array wordPosition
    function randomWord() {
        wordPosition = Math.floor(Math.random()*word.length); 
    }

    function refresh() {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        $("#Answer"+i).removeClass("AnswerWrong").addClass("Answer");
        $("#Answer"+i).removeClass("AnswerCorrect").addClass("Answer");
        }
    } 

    /***************************************************************************
     *  program   as a function                                                             *
     **************************************************************************/

    function next() {

        $("#Next").text("Continue");

        randomWord();
        randomGenerator();

        // make the decoy answers randomly
        if (wordPosition == 0 || wordPosition == 1) { 

            // In case the array is at the beginning: make the decoy start at the same spot as the wordPosition
            decoyWordPosition = wordPosition;
            } else {
                // start the decoy word after the word
                decoyWordPosition = wordPosition -2;
        }

        populateAnswers();

    }
    next();

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: There's no need to paste the entire HTML document, just the interested parts are ok :). Can we see how did you implemented your setTimeout function? Your problem might be something simple like a syntax mistake or something more complex.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm sorry I posted everything. I just wasn't sure if something else in my program was causing the problem, so I just showed everything (just in case). I honestly can't remember exactly what I tried before because I tried so many different ways. I think I may have done something like this:

'setTimeout(refresh(), 1000);
setTimeout(next(), 1000);'

The refresh and next function work normally and don't pause at all. I tried using an alert (which DOES pause) so I don't really get what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: AHHH! I figured out what I was doing wrong! I added in the brackets after my function, but I shouldn't have.

Comment: Looks like it was a simple syntax mistake, after all :) glad you spotted it yourself

Comment: Thanks MacK. Yes, it was. Like I stated before, I'm really new to all this, so I didn't really understand the syntax properly.  I noticed that if I had used quotes around the function, that would have worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just for other people who are trying to find the solution to the setTimeout feature.

I was using it like this:

setTimeout(myFunction(), 2000);

However, it won't work with the brackets after the function. You need to omit those brackets:

setTimeout(myFunction, 2000);